# Remove slashes from string using RegEx in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove all special characters except punctuation from a customer complaint textarea using this code:

```
var tmp = complaint;
complaint = new RegExp(tmp.replace(/[^a-zA-Z,.!?\d\s:]/gi, ''));
```

but it keeps placing "/" in front, and in back of the string after sanitizing.

Example:

```
 Hi, I h@ve a% probl&em wit#h (one) of your products.
```

Comes out like this

```
 /Hi, I have a problem with one of your products./
```

I want

```
 Hi, I have a problem with one of your products.
```

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: you `replace` which results in a string...then using that string you create a `regexp` object...no need to make a regexp object though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `complaint` is converted to a regular expression because you use the *RegExp()* constructor.

This probably isn't what you want.  (I assume you want `complaint` to be a string).

Strings and regular expressions are two completely different data types.

Your output demonstrates how JavaScript displays regular expressions (surrounded by `/` characters).

If you want a string, don't create a regular expression (i.e. remove the *RegExp constructor*).

In other words:

```
complaint = complaint.replace(/[^a-zA-Z,.!?\d\s:]/gi, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the RegExp constructor:

```
complaint = tmp.replace(/[^a-zA-Z,.!?\d\s:]/gi, '');
```

Comment: Doesn't even need a temp variable, `complaint = complaint.replace(...)`

Comment: @JeffWalters: you won't just clean up your Code, it's the Remedy to your Problem, See jahroy's answer.

Comment: Yes. It did. Thank you so much. I was banging my head trying to figure this one out. Now I know for future use.